# Can you really redefine keywords in C language?

Tags: c, keyword, c-preprocessor

Can you explain the code below?  How we can use `#define` for a keyword of C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define int int*
int main(void) {

    int *p;
    int q;
    p = 10;
    q = 5;
    printf("%d %d", p, q);
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10 5
```

Comment: That isn't defining a keyword. It's a macro. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593.aspx

Comment: You can't define keyword.

Comment: `#define int int*` -- Men have died for lesser crimes. Turn on your compiler warnings. This code is bogus.

Answer (score 7):

This `#define int int*` is  a preprocessor macro. If you want to define your own *synonyms* for types then use `typedef`. You cannot create keywords in a language you did not create.

Sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef int * myIntPtr;

int main(void) {

    int i = 10;
    myIntPtr x = &i;
    printf("%d", *x);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
10
```

Also semantically making an `int` to an `int *` makes no sense.

Comment: Doesn't `typedef` simply create synonyms? I mean `int*` is predefined, and any `struct` you would use `typedef` would have to be defined by user ?

Comment: @shree.pat18 - yeah, my statement was misleading - corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define a b
```

will change all "a" to "b" in your source after the #define

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define int int*

int main(void) {
    int *p;
    int q;
    p = 10;
    q = 5;
    printf("%d %d", p, q);
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

will change to

```
int main(void) {
    int **p;
    int *q;
    p = 10;
    q = 5;
    printf("%d %d", p, q);
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```